# Background task cancelled (ExecutionTimeExceeded)

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I got a background task that downloads a few JSON data files that works perfectly when I call it using Visual Studio. When the background task is called using the UserPresent trigger at startup it gets cancelled (ExecutionTimeExceeded.)

Is there anything I can do to run the background task without any limit?

Comment: Do you know how long your task takes? Do you call `Complete` on the deferral when you are done?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT It takes less than three seconds to the task to be completed, honestly. But at startup when all the programs are starting the three GET requests it does take longer and task gets cancelled. It reads a JSON file, makes a few requests, parses them and updates the file. That's all.

Comment: Do you complete the deferral?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Yeah, I do. I'm moving some code to the cloud so it only does one request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not, the time limit is dependent on trigger type, and as [MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187310.aspx) it can vary from 30 seconds to 10 minutes:

> CPU quotas:  Background tasks are limited by the amount of wall-clock usage time they get based on trigger type. Most triggers are limited to 30 seconds of wall-clock usage, while some have the ability to run up to 10 minutes in order to complete intensive tasks. Background tasks should be lightweight to save battery life and provide a better user experience for foreground apps. See Support your app with background tasks for the resource constraints applied to background tasks.

The backgroundtask should be a lightweight code - maybe you can redirect file download procedure to background transfer service and do some of heavy job in main app. You may also try with *MaintenanceTrigger*, there is a chance that constraints are lower for this one, but it fires once phone is connected to AC.

Comment: I see, thanks for the link. Is there a way to launch the app on the foreground at startup then? It's a desktop app and I want it to run when I'm using the battery.

Comment: @MiguelRipoll Maybe you can show a toast with timetrigger so the user will fire your app. As far as I know there is no way to run your app with trigger without user interaction, which is quite reasonable.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will run some code on the cloud instead. That way I''ll save battery and improve performance :P